# Выполнение пользовательского кода

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть *EditText* и *Button*.
В *EditText* пользователь пишет:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, код, указанный пользователем в *EditText* обработался.

Как этого добиться?

Comment: это на самом деле не просто. `Java`, в отличии например от `JavaScript` не может компилировать код в рантайме. Можете попробовать [вот эту библиотеку][1]. 


  [1]: https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker

Comment: @metalurgus Если учесть, что компилировать нужно не Java API, а Android API, то затея выглядит неосуществимой.

Comment: @pavlofff, скорее всего. Единственное, что мне приходит в голову - отправлять код на сервер, где он будет компилироваться в DEX, который впоследствии скачивать, и использовать при помощи `DexClassLoader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы этот код мог быть выполнен, он должен быть предварительно скомпилирован и запущен в обертке андроид-приложения - требуется контекст, форма куда выводить (активити) и тд., то есть фактически должно быть собрано новое приложение, так как вы не сможете вставить что то в уже скомпилированное и собранное приложение из которого хотите это запустить.

Я не вижу никаких способов осуществить вашу идею на практике, кроме как делать какую то мини-ide.

В качестве альтернативного решения можно предложить интерпретатор, который будет парсить ввод и выполнять заранее подготовленные действия по опознаным строкам.
Понятно, что все андроид API реализовать таким способом выглядит пугающе безнадежно, но для ограниченого набора классов это осуществимо вполне.

В общем случае задача выглядит почти  неосуществимой, по крайней мере без привлеченеия серьезных ресурсов.

В конце концов AIDE существует и даже сносно справляется с аналогичной задачей.